# How to Resolve this System.Typeload Exception

Tags: c#, .net, package, nuget, .net-assembly

I have this assignment for uni where we need to solve an LP using microsoft solver foundation (available through NuGet in Visual Studio). I have the following code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SolverFoundation;
using Microsoft.SolverFoundation.Common;
using Microsoft.SolverFoundation.Services;


SolverContext context = SolverContext.GetContext();
Model model = context.CreateModel();

Decision potato    = new Decision(Domain.RealNonnegative, "ingredient_potato");
Decision meat      = new Decision(Domain.RealNonnegative, "ingredient_meat");
Decision vegetable = new Decision(Domain.RealNonnegative, "ingredient_vegetable");

model.AddDecisions(potato, meat, vegetable);

model.AddConstraint("calorie", 800 * potato + 1000 * meat + 5 * vegetable == 600);
model.AddConstraint("protein", 150 <= 5 * potato + 500 * meat <= 250);
model.AddConstraint("vitamin", 10 * potato + 100 * vegetable >= 200);

model.AddGoal("price", GoalKind.Minimize, 5 * potato + 20 * meat + 7 * vegetable);

Solution solution = context.Solve(new SimplexDirective());
Console.Write(solution.GetReport());
```

when running it (.NET 6.0) i get the following error:

`System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.CallContext' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.'`

After some research I think it has to do with the .NET version I'm using, but I'm not sure, and if this were the case, I have no idea which other version is required. Any help at all with this would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Looks pretty outdated. You should check first with the latest non-core NET version if that fits. So try creating your project against NET Framework 4.8.

Comment: You might want to look at the warnings produced when compiling this code. There should be warning explaining that this package might be incompatible with .NET 6. You need older version, like 4.8